# checkbox with javascript && jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I will display a view, when I click on checkbox

I tried like this, but not work,
I need your help to fix the problem

**Models:**

```
public class DisplayData
{
    public bool ID { get; set; }
    public DisplayData(bool ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
 }

public class Element
{        
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
     public ActionResult Index()
     {            
        DisplayData Display = new DisplayData(false);
        return View(Display);
     }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model AppTwitter.Models.DisplayData

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myCheckbox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.CheckBoxFor(
 x => x.ID, 
 new {
    data_url = Url.Action("PartialDemo", "PartialDemo"), 
    id = "mycheckbox" 
  }
```

**myCheckbox.js:**

```
$(function () {
$('#mycheckbox').change(function () {
    var data = {};
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
});
});
```

**PartialDemoController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult PartialDemo()
    {                            
            var element = new Element();
            element.Descripcion = "Descripcion";
            return View(element);
    }
```

**PartialDemo.cshtml:**

```
 @model AppTwitter.Models.Element

   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion )
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion )

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion )
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem?

Comment: I will dispaly PartialDemo.cshtml when checkbox is checked, I'm not sure if my code in myCheckbox.js its correct?

Comment: You are binding wrong event with checkbox, use "click" instead of "change"

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan doesn't work, thanks

Comment: @Victor is the event is get fired? did you check it through alert message? and please check the error console in FF

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan event doesn't get fired and no error display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Victor, Now i got the issue. The id that you are assigning to checkbox doesn't get worked because you are using **@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ID)**. in this case the id of checkbox is generating dynamically hence "mycheckbox" doesn't get worked. So Instead assigning a id assign a class i.e

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(
 x => x.ID, 
 new {
       data_url = Url.Action("PartialDemo", "PartialDemo"), 
       @class = "mycheckbox" 
     }
)
```

and in javascript use below:

```
$(function () {
    $('.mycheckbox').click(function () {
      // your existing stuff
   });
});
```

Hope this will solve the problem